# Facebook login intent being called twice when using the Facebook login widget button

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin

I'm trying to put Facebook authentication into my kotlin app and i have it working successfully but each time the Facebook sign-in intent is called it pops up the activity a second time after you click continue to log in.  I have found people saying to just use a normal button instead of the Facebook one which I have tried and it removed the issue but did not look as nice.  I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to fix this without using a normal button.

Button:

```
  <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:onClick="@{loginSelectViewModel::goToFacebook}"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:paddingTop="32dp"
                android:paddingBottom="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_login_facebook"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_login_google"/>
```

View model function that calls the listener to trigger the function in my fragment:

```
fun goToFacebook(view: View){
        Timber.d("goToFacebook: Called")
        authListener?.onStarted()
        authListener?.onClickFacebookSignIn(view)
    }
```

Fragment function:

```
override fun onClickFacebookSignIn(view: View) {
        Timber.d("onClickFacebookSignIn: called")
        val loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance()

        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult>{
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
                Timber.d("loginmanager: onSuccess called")
                viewModel.facebookLogin(result?.accessToken)
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

        })

        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"))
    }
```

from what I can tell the on success is being called twice but the actually "onClickFacebookSignIn" function is only being called once.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a couple more hours I found out that the Facebook login button widget has additional functionality to call the Facebook login activity. My app was not set up to intercept this instance of the login activity so I ended up just creating a button that looks like a Facebook button. For anyone in need of this solution, this is what my buttons XML looks like.

```
<Button
                android:onClick="@{loginSelectViewModel::goToFacebook}"
                android:id="@+id/btn_login_facebook"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="#3B5998"
                android:backgroundTint="#3B5998"
                android:text="@string/login_select_facebook"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_login_google" />
```